# How to add text at a specific location below matlab subplots?

Tags: matlab, text

I want to add text at a certain location using `text`. I can place it anywhere in the graph, but how to move it below the x-axis in the subplot as shown by

> Here

(in red and blue color)

I am trying

```
text(0.8,0,'1901-1970','Fontsize',7, 'FontWeight','bold')
```

It results in the overlapping of text and xlabel.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use normalized units instead of what you're using in your script

Try this:

```
text(0.1,-0.2,'(1901-1970)','Units','normalized','color', 'b',...
'Fontsize',7, 'FontWeight','bold')
```